# What are These Long Addresses in the Loyce.com Address List?

Tags: address

I'm trying to understand Bitcoin address encodings. I understand there's three (four?) different address encodings P2PKH, P2SH, Bech32, and Bech32m (Bech32m just uses a different constant when XORing). They all encode the public key using Ripe160 (RIPEMD160?). I was able to use some libraries to extract the ripe160 encoded address, which should be 20 bytes, but there are some longer strings in this list of addresses with currency:

Bitcoin addresses with currency from [loyce.com](http://addresses.loyce.club/blockchair_bitcoin_addresses_and_balance_LATEST.tsv.gz)

```
34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo
**bc1qgdjqv0av3q56jvd82tkdjpy7gdp9ut8tlqmgrpmv24sq90ecnvqqjwvw97**
1P5ZEDWTKTFGxQjZphgWPQUpe554WKDfHQ
37XuVSEpWW4trkfmvWzegTHQt7BdktSKUs
38UmuUqPCrFmQo4khkomQwZ4VbY2nZMJ67
3Kzh9qAqVWQhEsfQz7zEQL1EuSx5tyNLNS
1FeexV6bAHb8ybZjqQMjJrcCrHGW9sb6uF
3LYJfcfHPXYJreMsASk2jkn69LWEYKzexb
bc1qa5wkgaew2dkv56kfvj49j0av5nml45x9ek9hz6
1LdRcdxfbSnmCYYNdeYpUnztiYzVfBEQeC
1AC4fMwgY8j9onSbXEWeH6Zan8QGMSdmtA
1LruNZjwamWJXThX2Y8C2d47QqhAkkc5os
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s
3Gpex6g5FPmYWm26myFq7dW12ntd8zMcCY
bc1q5shngj24323nsrmxv99st02na6srekfctt30ch
385cR5DM96n1HvBDMzLHPYcw89fZAXULJP
3LQUu4v9z6KNch71j7kbj8GPeAGUo1FW6a
**bc1q5pucatprjrqltdp58f92mhqkfuvwpa43vhsjwpxlryude0plzyhqjkqazp**
...
```

They start with `bc1` so that indicates Bech32, correct? When decoding using something like [bech32-buffer](https://slowli.github.io/bech32-buffer/) I get 32 bytes.

In doing some more digging, there's also this [scriptPubKey](https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/bitcoin_transfer/payment_script) encoding. Is that what these long encodings are? How do you differentiate them? I assume since the site is listing address with currency, I should be able to pull the ripe160 address from the script, are there any recommended parsers?

I found another [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89010/128353) which suggests doing pattern matching, and pulling the parsing code from Bitcoin Core. Am I heading down the correct path here?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these addresses? The answer very much depends on that.

Comment: [MULTISIG 3 OF 5](https://oxt.me/address/bc1q5pucatprjrqltdp58f92mhqkfuvwpa43vhsjwpxlryude0plzyhqjkqazp) P2WSH

Comment: @PieterWuille Learning, just want to understand all the different forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are bech32 addresses that encode a P2WSH scriptPubKey. The script that maps to those addresses contain the SHA256 of a script that will be revealed when the output is spent.

> They all encode the public key using Ripe160 (RIPEMD160?)

No. Addresses do not just encode public keys, nor do they necessarily encode a particular hash. It depends on the address type as it is dependent on the script that will be created.

Addresses beginning with a 1 encode the RIPEMD160 of the SHA256 of a public key and create P2PKH output scripts.

Addresses beginning with a 3 encode the RIPEMD160 of the SHA256 of a script and create P2SH output scripts.

bc1q addresses that are 42 characters long encode the RIPEMD160 of the SHA256 of a public key and create P2WPKH output scripts.

bc1q addresses that are 62 characters long encode the SHA256 of a script and create P2WSH output scripts.

bc1p addresses that are 62 characters long encode an X-only public key and create P2TR (Taproot) output scripts.