# Keypath spending: Verify destination address across address formats

Tags: address, public-key, taproot, bech32-address, p2tr

In a Tapscript Keypath Transaction *(there is an unrelated Scriptpath too)* I can have outputs to all possible address?

(I.e. to P2PKH, P2SH, P2WPKH / P2WSH and P2TR)

I have a list of addresses in all possible formats (including bech32(m)). How can I ensure / verify that the `scriptPubKey` is mappable to an address in this list?

The signing client has access to every part of transaction's construction.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Based off the taproot-workshop on Github I constructed this Transaction: `CTransaction(nVersion=1 vin=[CTxIn(prevout=COutPoint(hash=d66a46336b05c3f1550fd0983db887f4244570c06538cb05f68afed99d84ea71 n=0) scriptSig= nSequence=0)] vout=[CTxOut(nValue=0.49999000 scriptPubKey=0014a9d0682aaa00c327dbb3fd32c9dedcfcfbec1a69)] wit=CTxWitness() nLockTime=0)` I want `scriptPubKey` to be matchable against wallet addresses in various formats

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this answer and by looking how bitcoin core does it:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89010/123917